# .NET Remoting Pentest

Tags: exploit, .net

I am carrying out activities of Vulnerability Assessment and Penetration Test, specifically, I am testing an application written in .NET Remoting. Sniffing the communication (With Wireshark) of an authorized client I intercepted a request like the following.

```
.NET..............C...tcp://REMOTEIPADDRESS:9092/example.Admin.Server.DbAccess........application/octet-stream..........................SelectCompactDataset.example.Admin.Server.IAdminDbAccess, example.Admin.Server, Version=4.5.14.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null......example.]<sql><table name="visibility_criteria" query="SELECT * ETC ETC" /></sql>.
```

I, therefore, wonder how I can replicate the request in order to verify if even an unauthorized client can make the request and possibly manipulate the SQL query.